# How to set default selected value in asp.net mvc dropdownlist from model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selected

In model: `public class Language {int Id, string Name}`

In database: 1,language1; 2, language2, etc.

In controller: `ViewBag.Languages = new SelectList(GetLanguages(), "Id", "Name")`

In view: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LanguageId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Languages)`

In this case the default selected value is {1,language1} but i'd like to set other selected value for example {2, language2}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for the `SelectList` in order to pass a selected value:

```
int selectedValue = 2;
ViewBag.Languages = new SelectList(GetLanguages(), "Id", "Name", selectedValue);
```

Note that the fourth parameter there is the SelectedValue - I hardcoded "2" since that was the example you gave.  In practice, you can use whatever logic you actually need.